# Code for Google sheets automatically update data by copy - search - paste

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Sheet name Data Staff. And another sheet name Update Staff.
All 2 sheets have the same headers (ID staff, Name, Status, Day onboard, Day left, .v.v.), which sheet "Update Staff" is used for reviewing information and updating status by pasting a Staff ID and all rows of data will lookup by Staff ID. The below line has the same field so I can update data for this staff above like (Status: Working or Leave, Day left, v.v.v)
I need an automatic run when I type update information for staff in the sheet "Update Staff" and press update. It will search and go to lines have [Staff ID] and paste all data I just typed on "Update Staff" sheet to the correct line in the sheet "Data Staff"
I use macro record but when I run it, I found it not correct. Because when it can't find and go to line [Staff ID] to paste. Or if I use filter to find and update, it only uses [Staff ID] I recorded macro to use so although I change the staff id on sheet "Update Staff" it always updates to the line have the old "Staff ID" when I recorded macro.

I use macro record but when I run it, I found it not correct. Because when it can't find and go to line [Staff ID] to paste. Or if I use a filter to find and update, it only uses "Staff ID" I recorded macro to use so although I change the staff id on the sheet "Update Staff" it always updates to the line with have old "Staff ID" when I recorded macro.
I check Macro source and found, it does not paste a new "Staff ID" to filter to find a Staff. It just hides all data in the column. So only 1 "Staff ID" which recorded before is not in this hidden list and the result always is this "Staff ID"
Heare is macro source:
`

```
function filter() {
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    spreadsheet.getRange('A2').activate();
    spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Staff Data '), true);
    spreadsheet.getRange('A2').activate();
    var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria() .setHiddenValues(['MIE2021011128951', 'MIE2021020717643', 'MIE2021020717807', 'MIE2021020717829', 'MIE2021020717836', 'MIE2021020717950', 'MIE2021020717959', 'MIE2021020717962',
```